# Handling filesystem permission errors with mounted volumes in openshift 4

Tags: deployment, containers, openshift

We have little experience with Openshift, and we have a question/problem with permissions on mounted persistent volume that we would appreciate people's input with.
Please note that all of what we describe below, we are testing on a local CRC (Code-Ready Containers) cluster.

The goal is to create a very simple container that writes/persists data to a local volume. The volume is mounted using PersistentVolumeClaim on a specified path of the host. The problem we are having is that read/write operations to the mounted volume, don't work because of incorrect permissions. The problematic permissions seem to be set by Openshift when the pod gets started, and we don't understand why this is happening and how to prevent it.

We have narrowed down the problem to an example use case, which can be reproduced using the following files.

The example deployment, persistent volumes, and persistent volume claims are:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: random-file-generator
    namespace: test-case
spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: random-file-generator
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: random-file-generator
        spec:
            containers:
                - name: random-file-generator
                  image: default-route-openshift-image-registry.apps-crc.testing/test-case/random-file-generator:latest
                  imagePullPolicy: Always
                  volumeMounts:
                      - name: test-volume
                        mountPath: /test
            volumes:
                - name: test-volume
                  persistentVolumeClaim:
                      claimName: test-pvc
                      
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
    name: test-pvc
    namespace: test-case
spec:
    volumeMode: Filesystem
    accessModes:
        -   ReadWriteOnce
    resources:
        requests:
            storage: 1Gi
    storageClassName: ""
    volumeName: test-pv

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
    name: test-pv
    namespace: test-case
    labels:
        type: local
spec:
    capacity:
        storage: 1Gi
    accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
    hostPath:
        path: "/opt/crc-volumes/test"
```

The provisioner of the storage class is `kubevirt.io.hostpath-provisioner` and we haven't changed the
default configuration of CRC where we are doing the tests.

The custom image we are deploying (built using docker) is a simple one that contains only a script.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM docker.io/eclipse-temurin:17-jre-jammy
# Copy the shell script into the container
COPY random_file_generator.sh /usr/local/bin/random_file_generator.sh
# Make the script executable
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/random_file_generator.sh
# Fix permissions
RUN mkdir -p /test
RUN chgrp root /test
RUN chmod -R g=u /test
# Set the script as the entry point
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/random_file_generator.sh"]
```

The script in this image, simply "touches" a new file in the directory that is mapped to the persistent
volume (which is itself mapped to a host path as you can see above).

`random_file_generator.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash
touch /test/foo.txt
```

When the above image is and deployed and started, the following error occurs:

```
touch: cannot touch '/test/foo.txt': Permission denied
```

**Important to note:** This error only occurs when the persistent volume is mounted to the `/test`
directory. If there is no mounting, there is no error, and everything works as expected without having the data persisted.

Can you see the problem in what we are doing? Should we configure things differently at some level?

Thanks in advance for any input!